# Sum hours where we have consecutive turns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a view (SQL Server 2016) where I have the sum of hours of consecutive shifts with the same ID.

The shifts can only be equal to 1 or 2 or 3; and they are in this order: 1->2->3.  After shift 3 the next one is shift 1 in the next day.

A consecutive shift is where you have the same date and consecutive numbers (1->2, 2->3, 1->2->3), but also when you have consecutive dates and shift from 3 to 1 (3->1).

So I have something like this:

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ Date       ║ Shift       ║   Lenght    ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 101║ 2018-05-19 ║     2       ║      4      ║
║ 101║ 2018-05-19 ║     3       ║      16     ║
║ 101║ 2018-05-20 ║     1       ║      16     ║ 
║ 101║ 2018-05-20 ║     3       ║      14     ║
║ 202║ 2018-05-20 ║     1       ║      8      ║ 
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

And I'd like to get something like that (I don't need shifts anymore):

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║ Date       ║ Lenght      ║   
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 101║ 2018-05-19 ║ 36 (4+16+16)║      
║ 101║ 2018-05-20 ║     14      ║    
║ 202║ 2018-05-20 ║     8       ║    
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variant of gaps-and-islands.  I would suggest using `row_number()` but this is tricky because you have to measure the difference in *shifts*.

So:

```
select id, min(date), sum(length)
from (select s.*,
             (datediff(day, '2000-01-01', date) * 3 + shift - 1) as shift_counter,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date, shift) as seqnum
      from shifts s
     ) s
group by id, (shift_counter - seqnum)
order by id, min(date);
```

Here is a [rextester](http://rextester.com/VVMXT63665) showing it working.

Comment: This is not working for me, I executed it and it sums everything into the first row (lenght = 50) instead of giving me 2 rows with length 36 and 14.

Comment: @AndreaZanella . . . The code works.  You can check the link I just added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select ID,Date,SUM(Lenght) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED 
    PRECEDING)
    from shifts 
    order by id,date
```